# IIS URL Rewrite Block External Traffic outside the Network

Tags: url-rewriting, content-management-system, iis-8, umbraco8, web-traffic

We are currently hosting the Umbraco Content Management System (CMS) on our IIS server.

Our objective is to restrict access to the Umbraco Admin Login page exclusively for users outside our network. However, while implementing a Request blocking rule for the root Umbraco folder on Internet Information Services (IIS) using URL Rewrite, we encountered an issue wherein the rule indiscriminately blocks access to all subfolders as well.

To address this, we seek guidance on establishing a precise rule within IIS URL Rewrite that selectively prohibits access to the login page URL solely for individuals outside our internal network, while permitting access for users within the designated IP range of 000.00.*.*

[image]

This is how the current URL Rewrite rule looks where it is blocking everything under the root Umbraco folder.

Comment: People are used to learn your rewrite rules by reading the related XML elements from `applicationHost.config` file, not a screen shot.

Comment: Your problem is that your url rewrite rule is not working? if so, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Can't say I've tried this. The pattern ^umbraco/?$ should match the top level segment only, but I'm not sure that's what you want as it may let other longer URLs through, You probably want the URL to target ^umbraco/login/?$  . I think you can ignore the #s found in these URLs as those are for Angular JS client side routing.

Comment: The Umbraco docs explain how to do this for the various tech stacks here: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/security/security-hardening. This is more inline with how I do URL rewriting, as Lex Li says we don't usually configure via the IIS user interface itself.